# Tron API cURL-how to get the wallet address from owner_address

Tags: api, curl, tron

I have a problem. I have an owner_address.
I want to get the TRON wallet address from owner_address, but when I try to send a request

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"value": "sa"}' https://api.trongrid.io/wallet/getaccount
```

I'm getting empty JSON (12 headers, but the object is empty), help me out.
**More important**.
The owner_address is valid, I found this address in my wallet address in transactions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solving by sending HTTP request on endpoint: https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/<owner_address>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).